# Does a language have the same time complexity as its complement language?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np, co-np

If $L ⊆ \{0, 1\}^*$ is a language, then we denote by $ \overline{L}$ the complement of $L$

For example, the definition of $coNP$ is $coNP =\{L | \overline{L} \in NP\}$

The complement of $SAT$ language is $\overline{SAT} = \{\phi | \phi$ is  not satisfiable$\}$

Of course, there are other $P$ languages

What I want to ask is，Does a language have the same time complexity as its complement language?

Comment: What is the "time complexity" of a language? Do you mean the complexity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Consider decidable language $L$ and its complement $\bar L$. Note that the decidability of $L$ implies the decidability of $\bar L$. Thus, there exists a TM $D$ that can decide $L$ in $\text{TIME}(f(n))$. Similarly, there exists a TM $D'$ that can decide $\bar L$ in $\text{TIME}(g(n))$. We now consider three cases:

1. $f(n) \text{ is } \Omega(g(n))$

We then construct a more efficient TM $D_L$ such that

$$ \forall x \in \{0, 1\}^*. D_L(x) = \overline {D'(x)}$$

That is, $D_L$ simulates $D'$ on input $x$ and flips the answer. Then $D_L$ decides $L$ in $\text{TIME}(g(n))$

2. $g(n) \text{ is } \Omega(f(n))$

We then construct a more efficient TM $D_{\bar L}$ such that

$$ \forall x \in \{0, 1\}^*. D_{\bar L}(x) = \overline {D(x)}$$

That is, $D_{\bar L}$ simulates $D$ on input $x$ and flips the answer. Then $D_{\bar L}$ decides $\bar L$ in $\text{TIME}(f(n))$.

3. $f(n) \text { is } \Theta(g(n))$

$D$ and $D'$ decide $L$ and $\bar L$ respectively in the same time asymptotically (i.e. $\text{TIME}(f(n)) = \text{TIME}(g(n))$).

Thus, both $L$ and $\bar L$ can always be decided in the same time asymptotically.